# docker : php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known","1"

Tags: docker

i keep getting this error for my docker build :

```
"0":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not 
known","1":"#1 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
```

However, if i **docker-compose down** and then **docker-compose up** it works for a coupe of mins and then crashes again.

Is this to do with the network cache. Is there somthing that i should clear ?

this is my docker compose file. --you will note that i do provide a link to database:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: ./developer
    ports:
      - "8228:80"
    links:
      - database
    volumes:
      - total-sync:/var/www/html:nocopy
    env_file:
      - env

  database:
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports: 
            - "3907:3316"
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=default
        volumes:
            - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - ./db/mysqlconf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
            - ./mysqladata2.3.4:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8583:80"
    links:
      - database

volumes:
    total-sync:
      external: true
    dbdatas:
      driver: local
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Before stopping all containers, check whether the MySQL container is still running - maybe it crashed?

Comment: @NicoHaase  checked. no errors in the log. any other ideas what it might be?

Comment: And the MySQL service is not stopped nor restarted right before that error message occurs?

Comment: @NicoHaase. hi mate. no the mysql is still working. however it not accessable . this is the message when i tried to connect via mysqladmin:  mysqli_real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known